# Core Data - UIManagedDocument won't open

Tags: iphone, ios, uimanageddocument

I am using Core Data to store a few simple strings related to each user. When the app first starts, everything seems to be fine.  The database opens, and I am successfully able to save and retrieve data.

However, after some usage, sometimes the `UIManagedDocument` I use will just not open when the app starts.  Here is the method I use for that (done in the app delegate):

```
-(void)initManagedDocument{
@try {
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataBase"];

    self.managedDocument = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]){

        [self.managedDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
            if (success) {
                [self documentIsReady];
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Could not open document");
            }

        }];

    }else{

        [self.managedDocument saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success){

            if (success) {
                [self documentIsReady];
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Could not create document");
            }
        }];
    }
}
@catch (NSException *e) {

}

}
```

This code gets called from my app's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.  The `saveToURL` half of the if-statement gets called initially, and returns a success.  Then in the following few calls the `openWithCompletionHandler:` gets called, and returns successfully.

However, at some point after using the app for awhile, the `openWithCompletionHandler:` returns success = FALSE.  I am not sure why, or how the `UIManagedDocument` gets messed up.  The URL still seems to be the same, and the `fileExistsAtPath` is still returning `YES`.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?  Or if there is a way for me to debug and find out what the actual error is that is causing the open to fail?

Comment: Hey, I am having the same problem. Any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried turning on `com.apple.coredata.ubiquity.logLevel` or `com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug` see [CORE DATA AND ICLOUD DEBUGGING TIPS](http://ife.li/core-data-and-icloud-debugging-tips/)